# Obtain java primitive from mongo aggregation without a new output class

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have an aggregation:

```
AggregationResults<Integer> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
  Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.group().count().as("value"), 
    Aggregation.project("value").andExclude("_id"), 
  MyData.class, Integer.class);
```

In the mongo shell, when I don't have to map an object, I get: `{ "value" : 2 }`

However, I get the following error when trying to map this lone value: `org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for java.lang.Integer`

Can I get around having to create a new output type class, when I only want to get a single java primitive?

Note: I'm going this approach instead of db.collection.count() for the sharding inaccuracies stated here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AggregationResults<DBObject> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
  Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.group().count().as("value"), 
    Aggregation.project("value").andExclude("_id"), 
MyData.class, DBObject.class);

int count = (Integer) result.getUniqueMappedResult().get("value");
```

So, not exactly what I wanted, because I still have to traverse over an object, but it's not any more code than I had before and I didn't need to make another class as the outputType.